# How to Post Array Parameter in html to Controller with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I want send some data array in html to my controller using ajax.

```
<input type='number' class='form-control' name='labor_service['service_1005']' value='20'>
<input type='number' class='form-control' name='labor_service['service_1006']' value='10'>
```

then my expectation result like this

```
{
    'labor_service' => [
        {
            'service_1005' => 20
        },
        {
            'service_1006' => 10
        }
    ]
}
```

then, how to push the expectation to ajax for saving into controller

Thankyou

Comment: what are you using to make the ajax request: jQuery, fetch API or good old XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: @jumper85 using jQuery

Comment: ok, then it should work if you just use `jQuery('#form').serialize()` and provide the result to `data` of your ajax call
I'm no laravel expert, but as it is PHP, it should handle the request like you would expect as a nested associative array

Comment: Can you update your question with your ajax code

Answer (score 0):

the easy way it to format the inputs names

```
<input type='number' class='form-control' name="labor_service[]['service_1005']" value='20'>
<input type='number' class='form-control' name="labor_service[]['service_1006']" value='10'>
```

Comment: i have to try this , but when i console.log in js, only value 20 showed. how is that?

Comment: @DhiemasGanisha the quotes where messed up, fixed the name attribute